# Why there 'can't help improve' is used, not 'can't help improving'?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases, phrase-choice

I'm doing my grammar practice in which a question confuses with me.

> I'm afraid your suggestion can't help ( ) the service of their shop.
>
> A. improve
>
> B. improving
>
> C. in improving
>
> D. for improving

Definitely C and D both are inappropriate, but the correct option is A, I do not know why, and I can not find an explanation in my dictionary to give the option C a similar record in which 'can't help do' can be used.

My dictionary said so (in Japanese):

> can’t [(よりかたく)cànnot] hélp doing ＝ (主に米)can’t [(よりかたく)cànnot] hélp bùt do *

Translated into English:

> can’t [(more informal than)cànnot] hélp doing ＝ (chiefly GA)can’t [(more informal than)cànnot] hélp bùt do *

And there has no 'cannot help do' or 'can't help do'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Cannot help doing* and *cannot help but do* mean *cannot stop oneself from doing* something.

> He's sometimes annoying, but I can't help liking him.

However, this is **not** the sense required in your sentence. *I'm afraid that* implies that the suggestion will not improve the service, so *can't help* here means *cannot be of any assistance.*

I would say *can't help to improve*, but as this isn't one of the options I would use A or C - not B because that implies the other sense of *can't help.*

Comment: I agree. I wouldn't say _can't help improve_.

Comment: @ColinFine - Kate - "People can't help improve health services if they don't know who to talk to.", "OK, so we can't help improve the weather this month… But we can help you love Mondays." "Why NPS and CSAT scores can't help improve your customer experience strategy." "If you don't measure it, you can't help improve it, and our insights will help accelerate change in our sector at a global level."

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I find all those odd. I find a base verb natural after _help_  but not after (the idiom) _can't help_.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - I didn't mean to imply that _help improve_ was wrong, just that I prefer to include _to_.